# Hints to solve: $(5\cdot 3^{m})+4=n^{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Consider all possible integers $n \geq 0$ such that $$(5\cdot 3^{m})+4=n^{2}$$ holds for some corresponding integer $m \geq 0$. Find the sum of all such $n$.

My effort:

$5\cdot 3^{m}$ means number end in $5$ , $+4$ means number end in $9$. So perfect square should have $9$ as last digit, so $n$ can be $3$ or $7$. Hence sum equal to $10$.

Please tell is this correct? this was hit and trial kind stuff, please provide method which not include hit and trial.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $ 5 \cdot 3^m = n^2 - 4 = (n-2)(n+2) $. What can you say about $ n-2 $ and $ n+2 $, given this equality?

Comment: one should be $5$ at least.

Comment: Yes - now conclude.

Comment: @Ayushakj Yes, that gives two cases.

Comment: @Aaron got it !

Comment: but tell me one thing that why we should assume two equalities to be prime (n+2) and (n-2), to have factor of $5$ we can have $15$, $25$.... so on as the value of n+2 or n-2.

Comment: @Ayushakj Because $n+2$ and $n-2$ differ by $4$, they can't both be multiples of $3$, which means that all the factors of $3$ have to be together.  That means either the factorization is $1$ and $5\cdot 3^m$ (in which case $m=0$), or $5$ and $3^m$, which implies $m=0$ or $2$.  When you said one should be $5$, I thought you meant one of the factors was equal to $5$, which is true in all of the solutions.